# Getting image source from image element using $(this).find("");

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently stuck trying to get the image source (eg: ./imgs/image.jpg) from an image element.

I've managed to get it working, partially, by using the following:

```
var image = document.getElementById("home-our-doughnuts-box-image").getAttribute("src");
```

But I need to use `$(this).find("#MY_IMAGE_ELEMENT_ID_HERE").getAttribute("src");` so it references the correct box and image (I have multiple containers with elements in them that share the same ID, same with the box).

So how can I access the images src attribute to return the unresolved path using `$(this).find()`, as it's not working ?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I am using `this` because I have assigned a `click` function to each of the boxes. So need to use `$(this)` to reference that particular box.

Full Code:

```
   box.onclick = function() {
     var image = $(this).find("#home-our-doughnuts-box-image").getAttribute("src");

     alert(image);

     doughnutExpandedName.text($(this).find("#home-our-doughnuts-box-name").text());
     doughnutExpandedDesc.text($(this).find("#home-our-doughnuts-box-desc").text());

};
```

Comment: IDs are unique, so if you're having a problem then `$(this).find("#ID")` won't solve it.

Comment: jQuery equivalent for `getAttribute` is `attr`, or use `[0]` to get DOM element as in Archer's comment

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It will find it, if `this` only has 1 instance of an element with that ID.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I have updated the question.

Comment: Jumping between vanilla JS and jQuery is not a great idea; if you are going to load jQuery you should use it as much as possible.

Comment: @AndyG Thanks for the heads up. Sorry for the stupid question but which parts of the code am I using jquery and which parts am I not?

Comment: Post your html structure. I am not able to figure out does `this` element contains target image or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var src = $(this).find("#MY_IMAGE_ELEMENT_ID_HERE").attr("src");
```

Comment: $(this).find("#MY_IMAGE_ELEMENT_ID_HERE")[0].getAttribute("src"); will work. You are mixing Jquery with javascript.

Comment: You are getting a jQuery object when you use find and .getAttribute is for vanilla DOM. .attr is a jQuery function therefore it works in this case :)

Comment: You can still convert it to a native DOM element as others pointed out.

Comment: @Tanmay I feel like an absolute moron. I think what I need to do when researching how to do things is always make sure I add "Jquery" instead of "Javascript" in my search term. Thanks.